# How to show the "most popular" tags

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have an input box where users can enter tags when they ask a question. They are separated by commas, like this:

```
test1, test2, test3, test4
```

My `questions` table structure is:

[image]

To show the tags of a question I just use `explode(",", $qinfo['tags'])` and then a `foreach` loop.

But, I don't know how I can display tags from most popular to least popular on a separate "popular tags" page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your criteria for popularity? Views from your table?

Comment: @the_red_baron The number of questions that are tagged with it (the "views" is only the number of times the question has been viewed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `tags` and `questions_tags` table.

```
tags
----
id
name

questions_tags
-------------
id
question_id
tag_id
```

And get tags sorted by popularity:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(qt.id) AS total
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN questions_tags qt ON t.id=qt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I suggest you to keep the `tags` field in the `questions` table. Use it for caching. eg: if you're displaying a single question, no need to query the `tags` and `questions_tags` table.

Comment: One question, would `qt` be the questions table in the SQL above?

Comment: `qt` is a new table, `questions_tags`. It "connects" the `tags` and `questions` table. See [Pivot Table tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You should so put the tags into other table and separately (not separated by commas).

Comment: This sounds like a much better way. But, how would that work though, like each time a question is asked put all the tags that were put in the input box into the table (each tag separately)?

Comment: Well, bsdnoobz explained what I meant by providing the structure in his answer and kudos for him for taking time to explain :)